# Execution order of tasks scheduled on an event loop (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio, event-loop, python-3.10

I am still learning the asyncio module in python 3.10. Below is a code I wrote trying to understand how to run coroutines as tasks on an event loop. the output I am getting is different from what I expected. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong or if there is something I misunderstood.

```
import asyncio 
    async def f(x):
        try:
            print(f"Inside f({x})...")
            await asyncio.sleep(x)
            print(f'slept for {x} seconds!!')
            return x
        except asyncio.CancelledError:  # Execute this part only when the task is cancelled.
            print(f'Cancelled({x})')
    
    async def main():
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    
        task1 = loop.create_task(f(1), name="task1")
        task2 = loop.create_task(f(2), name="task2")
        task3 = loop.create_task(f(3), name="task3")
    
        print(task1.done())
        print(task2.done())
        print(task3.done())
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

> **Output:**
>
> False False False Inside f(1)... Inside f(2)... Inside f(3)...
> Cancelled(3) Cancelled(1) Cancelled(2)

I expect this code to exit main() immediately after `print(task3.done())` and only run the exception handling part of the coroutine function f(x), but the event loop runs the functionalities of f(1), f(2) and f(3) exactly one time before actually exiting.
My doubts are

1. Why do all the tasks on the event loop run once  before getting cancelled?
2. What is the execution order (if there is any, is it fixed or random?)

**Edit:**
I first tried using `task1 = asyncio.create_task(f(1), name = "task1")`. Then I used `loop.create_task()`. Both give same output(which is to be expected I guess).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the line "task1 = loop.create_task(f(1), name="task1")" to be "task1 = asyncio.create_task(f(1), name="task1")"

Comment: I tried too that but the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is finishing before your asynchronous tasks are done, so they are all being cancelled.  The call to `done()` just prints that they're not done.

You need to add `await(task1)`, etc. in addition to the previous answer if you want to give your tasks the chance to finish.  Or just
`await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, task3)` to wait for all of them in one call.

Comment: I want the program to jump out of `main()` (so,the tasks automatically have to be cancelled)  hence I didn't use `await`. 
But what I don't understand is, why are the tasks running for one time before they got cancelled!

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting to have happen.  The three asynchronous tasks start as soon as you call `f(1)`, `(f2)`, and `f(3)`.  You don't have to `start` them or anything.  Don't be confused with threading/multiprocessing where you have to both `start()` and then `join()` a thread.  Async starts immediately, and `await` just waits until its done.

Comment: In that case, the output should show _Inside f()..._ messages followed by _false_ messages. But the _false_ messages are printed first indicating `print(task1.done())`  statement is executed before the tasks. After `print(task3.done())` gets executed, I am expecting the program to exit from 'main()' by calcelling all the tasks. So those  _Inside f()..._ messages shouldn't even be printed according to my understanding

Comment: You. misunderstood my "start immediately".  I meant "are eligible to run immediately."  When they actually start is up to the scheduler.  Whether the `print(task1.isdone())` gets called first or the `inside f(1)` gets called first cannot be relied upon.   It's even possible that you'll see `false; false; false; cancelled; cancelled; cancelled;` because none of the tasks have begun.  You have *NO* guarantee of the order that things are going to run.